# In C# could we imagine writing our own events without writing delegates?

Tags: java, c#, delegates

I learned the object-oriented in Java. Now in develop in C#. This means that I never really understood the functioning of delagates but I know how to use them.

Lately I discovered this page http://java.sun.com/docs/white/delegates.html.

If Java is able to create event without delagates is it possible to do the same in C#? Could we imagine writing our own events without writing a single delegate?

(Question already asked in french [here](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d549959/dotnet/csharp/delegates-peux-sen-passer/))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you could use a single-method interface instead of a delegate. You'd also need an implementation of the multi-cast nature of delegates, both in terms of add/remove and invoke. It would be tough to have a *single* class implementing multicast and also implementing `Invoke` in a typesafe way, however, due to the interfaces having different numbers and types of parameters. You could have a bunch of them of course: `Multicast<T>`, `Multicast<T1, T2>` etc. (The same class would handle asynchronous execution too, probably.)

The other pain in the neck is that you could only implement the interface once per class, even if you wanted several different handlers - so you'd have a lot of nested classes.

There's little that's particularly *magical* about delegates - they're just a very useful abstraction, and with the syntactic sugar of lambda expressions, anonymous methods and expression trees, they're even nicer.

Comment: Yes but they won't be events in the sense of CLR events (found in metadata), it would be a implementation of the event pattern, unrecognized by the CLR and tooling as events.

Comment: Sure - but I see the spirit of the question as "imagine if we didn't have CLR events"; there'd be no such thing as tooling for events.

Answer (score 7):

No, you can't do events in C# without delegates. In C#, events are defined as delegates:

> An `event` is a member that enables a class or object to provide notifications. An `event` is declared like a field except that the declaration includes an `event` keyword and the type must be a delegate type.

However, you could mimic events using the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Microsoft's [answer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vjsharp/bb188664.aspx) to Sun's White Paper is worth reading.

Comment: You could simulate the same thing that Java does. Of course, what you would do would not be compatible with the current concept of an "event" defined in the C# language.

Comment: +1 excellent link, though I don't think it's correct to say that we couldn't even imagine writing our own events without delegates.

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty old document and look where it's gotten them. You can do the exact same thing in .NET if you want. All the "Java Way" is doing is taking advantage of inheritance. That's fine but for many the "function pointer" semantic is much more straightforward and less verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can use predefined delegates. (I'm not sure what's your level of experience and what are you really asking about)

Answer (score 0):

Why on earth would you want to do that?
I mean, if you have a rules engine, or commands that are more than just eventhandlers, then sure: You will want to implement an interface, because you will have state and behavior besides the actual piece of code you want to fire.

But if providing some code to fire when the event is raised, then there's no reason to not use delegates.

Delegates are thin abstractions over method/function pointers and as such they add very little overhead. And IMO, one should not add overhead just for the sake of it.

Comment: @Robert: The OP never said he wanted to do this - he's only asking about it as a thought experiment, as far as I can tell. In particular, thinking how you'd achieve the same effect as some new feature in ways which don't require that new feature is a good way of *understanding* new stuff.

Comment: I really read it as if he asked whether that would be a good thing.
Must be me being a non-native speaker uhm reader/writer.
But thx anyways for the clarification. :-)